# Why do I get an error message when calling MaTeX in MMA13.1?

Tags: matex

when calling `MaTex` in MMA13.1

```
<< MaTeX`
```

I get this

```
AbsoluteFileName::zfname: The file name cannot be an empty string.
```

In MMA12.3 works fine?!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** Version 1.7.9 addresses this.

---

I expect that this is harmless and the package still works.

This is very likely because you have an invalid entry in your system `PATH`, namely an empty entry. If you remove this empty entry from your path, the error message will go away. Note that on Windows there are two settings: the system PATH and the user PATH. Verify both.

The reason why this message appears only in 13.1 is that the messages issues by `AbsoluteFileName` have changed again, and selective message suppression does not catch `AbsoluteFileName::zfname`. In other programming languages one can generally count on a given error condition triggering the same exception in all versions. One can catch one specific exception and handle it appropriately. It may seem like one could do the same in Mathematica by detecting specific messages. But message tags change frequently and without notice from version to version. Messages seem to be treated as something to be read by a user, and not something to be handled programmatically.

Comment: yes, it works regardless of the error, but it is annoying:-)

Comment: @valarmorghulis Can you test version 1.7.9 and report back?

Comment: `ResourceFunction["MaTeXInstall"][]` is not working? it gives : `First::nofirst: {} has zero length and no first element.` and `URLSave::invurl: Lookup[First[Lookup[FunctionRepository`$40be1885ce094c549834d7fc6e0831bb`json$38243,assets]],browser_download_url] is not a valid URL`

Comment: @valarmorghulis Thanks for the note. This is fixed now, please try again.

Comment: now it works nicely and the error disappears with MaTeX 1.7.9. Thanks!